# Is it possible to use Hibernate on a Desktop with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

When following the typical Windows 10 tutorials for enabling hibernation (e.g. [this one](https://windowsreport.com/hibernate-start-menu-windows-10/)), I've noticed that some options don't appear on my desktop. Is it because it might not have the same awareness hardware a laptop does? Or is there a hidden way somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Why is the `Hibernate` option not part of the default power options???

[image]

Comment: why would I use hibernation on a desktop with Windows 10 when I can use sleep?

Comment: "Why is the Hybernate option not part of the default power options???" - Because `Hybernate ` isn't a valid option, the option is called **Hibernate**, but it can be disabled by your system administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks, fixed the typo. In the answer I had it right, but here I had written it with a "y" for some reason.

Comment: @vssher, `Hibernate` and `Sleep` are different things. When in hibernation, the computer *actually* shuts down. Power consumption and noise are much different under each option.

Comment: Is this a personal computer or owned by a business? The biggest question with power states is always "does your hardware support it". Also, have you checked for and installed any updated drivers?

Comment: It's a personal computer, and, apparently, it does support it, because I've tested it and it does work. It's quite the blessing, because I had been shutting it down and having to reset all my workspace every day for the last 2 months.

Comment: Open CMD as Administrator and enter `powercfg -h on`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `command prompt` *with administrator permissions*:

```
powercfg /hibernate on
```

**Don't forget to check that you have enough space on your main drive**, because everything in your RAM will be stored in your HD while your PC is hibernating.

Comment: `powercfg /hibernate on` seems to superseed the GUI operation I've mentioned in my answer also.

Comment: Difficult to say which answer is better, but I think I'll go with yours if you accept the edit or improve it in some other fashion. I had tried `powercfg /hibernate on` previously, but, for some reason, it hadn't worked out.

Comment: Curiously, didn't work on its own this time (I think it worked previously for me) on Windows 10, had to actually also go and use the GUI the way Philippe's answer describes it.

Answer (score 3):

Many guides are outdated, even some of Microsoft's own tutorials. [This tutorial](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-hibernate-mode-windows-10/), however, seems to be spot-on:

1. Look for `Control Panel` with your <kbd>Windows</kbd> bottom-left icon.
2. Look for `Power Options`.
3. Click on <kbd>Choose what the power buttons do</kbd>.
4. Click on the *admin-protected* <kbd>Change settings that are currently unavailable</kbd>.
5. The `Hibernate` option should now be available for you to enable.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can activate it on the desktop is with a shortcut that executes the following command:

```
shutdown /h
```