# Why is Windows 10 Coming out of Hibernate?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

## 1. The Problem

After enabling `Hibernate` on my desktop with what was discussed in [this other StackExchange question](https://superuser.com/q/1504985/1066947), for days, everything seemed fine. But then, out of nowhere and for no reason — it happens with or without pending OS updates —, my PC now sometimes wakes up out of `Hibernate`. I'm puzzled as to why this is happening.

## 2. What I've tried

So far, I've tried to change some less known configurations that seemed to solve the problem, but I'm afraid didn't:

1. Shutting down my wireless mouse (`Logitech Master MX 2S`) and keyboard (`Logitech K780`), and taking the USB receiver out (my PC doesn't have Bluetooth).

   - This was to make sure no accidental signal was coming in to the PC while I was away, and it didn't solve the problem.
2. Go to <kbd>Change Automatic Maintenance Settings</kbd> and disable <kbd>Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time</kbd>.
3. Go to <kbd>Change when the computer sleeps</kbd> → <kbd>Change advanced power settings</kbd> → <kbd>Sleep</kbd> → <kbd>Allow wake timers</kbd> → disable this setting.

   - This is my last recent attempt. I haven't been able to confirm that it is the solution yet.

Does anyone know *what is the root of this problem*?

Comment: Update BIOS, Cbipset and all other drivers.  Then, if you have it, turn off Modern Standby. Then (as you did) turn off your mouse and also turn off wireless. Make sure the laptop is charged, Hibernate again and see if it stays hibernated.

Comment: Use the command `powercfg /lastwake` to see which device last woke up the computer.

Comment: `powercfg /lastwake` is very useful, but I guess I'm gonna have to wait until the next involuntary wake. Until then, [this tutorial](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/31/find-pc-wakes-stop/) seems incredibly useful. `powercfg -waketimers` reveals that I have an event to be triggered by my `UpdateOrchestrator` at 23:34. I thought I had disabled these wake timers... now I'm gonna try to disable them again somehow.

Comment: I've just added a note about `SYSTEM` permissions to a [spectacular community answer](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop/973029#973029) to this problem. I hope that tutorial solves the problem... Boy, did Microsoft really messed this thing up...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conclusively stop wake timers from waking Windows 10 desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

I still cannot believe this issue has been going on for so long in Windows OS's. It dates back to at least Windows 7 or around 2015. A really thorough tutorial on how to solve it was posted for [this other StackExchange question](https://superuser.com/q/973009/1066947).

However, there was a missing piece about having to use `SYSTEM` permissions to be able to alter some of the configurations, which I've added here and to the aforementioned answer-tutorial. It seems to have solved the problem, but I'm not 100% sure, you never know if Windows will come up with some nasty way of tripping you up.

## The Missing Piece

> Altering the `UpdateOrchestrator`'s tasks now requires `SYSTEM` permissions, neither `administrator` nor `TrustedInstaller` permissions.

[One of the ways of going around this is by](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/no-permission-to-disable-a-task-in-task-scheduler/4ec2c460-7c2f-4593-b84f-c9b1687ae797):

1. Installing Microsoft's own [`PsTools`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools).
2. Opening <kbd>Command Prompt</kbd> as and administrator and `cd` into your local `PsTools` folder.
3. Executing:

   ```
   psexec.exe -i -s %windir%\system32\mmc.exe /s taskschd.msc
   ```
4. Going to the `UpdateOrchestrator` and disabling the `Reboot` task(s), as previously mentioned.